# How to implement MVVM with NavigationService in Silverlight 4?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I'm new to Silverlight and NavigationService. I try to adopt them with MVVM. I found [this link](http://garfoot.com/blog/2010/09/silverlight-navigation-with-the-mvvm-pattern/) but it don't work for me, may be I do something wrong. (It don't has sample solution)

I want to know, are there any website/example out there?

Comment: Another for you to look at:https://bitbucket.org/dbeattie/navdemo/src

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mr. Robert just update [Silverlight Navigation With the MVVM Pattern](http://garfoot.com/blog/2010/09/silverlight-navigation-with-the-mvvm-pattern/) and add [sample code](http://garfoot.com/samples/NavigationSample.zip), after I downloaded it, everything is clear!

Comment: Sample code here for a NavigationService in SL4:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8866751/mvvm-and-navigationservice